# Sending an email does not work from the IDLE

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all, I know there is a lot of questions similar, but this is different.

I wrote a program to read users' usage logs and email them. He're what it is so far (Python 2.7):

```
with open ('c:\\users\\public\\log.txt', 'r') as myfile:
     data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

import smtplib

fromaddr = 'you_would_like_to_see@not_exactly.comma'
toaddrs  = 'you_would_like_to_see@not_exactly.comma'
msg = data

username = 'xyz'
password = 'xyz'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

So when I run the program in console, it works. I get an email in my gmail inbox. However, if I run the program in the .py format, it does not email. If I try again, but in console, it still will work. Does anyone know why?

Some information that may be useful:
The file is felmail.py (no class called that)
I'm using 2.7

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Thanks for showing us your password and email address.

Comment: You do realize that that was a joke...I'll change it though
I'm running it in console and in .py

Comment: There's no use in editing because everyone can see the revisions.

Comment: I think this is mostly a problem with how you have saved the script, and how you are executing it. try to debug it using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html), do an `import pdb` at the top and add a `pdb.set_trace()` call in your script to find out where exactly is your script failing, with what errors.